# google analytics management api - Insert goals - 403

Tags: google-analytics-api

I recently requested access to GA Management API and received the email confirming the whitelisting of my project 3 days ago.
I am working on GA Management API to create goals but I am still getting the following error:

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Your
>   project does not have access to this
>   feature."}],"code":403,"message":"Your project does not have access to
>   this feature."}}

About my context and in addition:

- i've recreated a new client API key (web application) to be sure to get a new token (referring the token lifespan) but it has not solved the problem.
- Custom dimensions creation works on the same project id
- Goals listing also works
- I use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit" scope to try to create my goals
- I code using Javascript language

Thank you for your help and feel free to ask me any additional information.

Comment: there should be a group you where added to as well you can normally get help for beta projects there.

Comment: I am having the same problem. The google developer group is called google-analytics-analyticsjs. But the group reads: On November 30, 2015, this group will be closed to all new discussions, questions, and announcements. 

After that date, we ask that you use Stack Overflow to ask and answer questions about any of the Google Analytics APIs.