# Google Analytics Management Api Insert Goal: 403 Insufficient permission .net

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I got the confirmation Email regarding project whitelisting from Google Analytics team and tried inserting a Goal but got the error.

```
{The service analytics has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Your project does not have access to this feature. [403]
Errors [
        Message[Your project does not have access to this feature.] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ParseResponse>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()}
```

I'm using the Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 (1.32) nuget package for creating the goal

The code I've written is:

```
            var goal = new Goal();
            goal.AccountId = accId;
            goal.WebPropertyId = websiteId;
            goal.ProfileId = profileId;

            goal.Name = "Api Funnel";
            goal.Active = true;
            goal.Created = new DateTime();


            goal.Type = "URL_DESTINATION";
            var urlDestinationDetails = new UrlDestinationDetailsData();
            urlDestinationDetails.MatchType = "EXACT";

            var stepData0 = new UrlDestinationDetailsData.StepsData();
            stepData0.Number = 0;
            stepData0.Url = "step1";
            stepData0.Name = "Step1";

            var stepData1 = new UrlDestinationDetailsData.StepsData();
            stepData1.Number = 0;
            stepData1.Url = "step2";
            stepData1.Name = "Step2";

            var steps = new List<UrlDestinationDetailsData.StepsData>();

            urlDestinationDetails.Steps = steps;
            goal.UrlDestinationDetails = urlDestinationDetails;
            goal.UrlDestinationDetails.Url = "step2";
            var request = analyticsService.Management.Goals.Insert(goal, accId, websiteId, profileId);
            request.Execute();
```

Scope is set to analytics.edit :

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit

Still, I'm facing the issue

[google analytics management api - Insert goals - 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064967/google-analytics-management-api-insert-goals-403)

Also referred to the respective post but couldn't find any answer.

All the get requests were processed successfully returning the correct data.
Now, I want to insert a goal but having this issue.

Also asked using the issue tracker of google

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71837169

Also the developer forum group is closed now : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-analytics-management-api

Please feel free to ask any additional information.

Comment: My own experience of using the Google API's is that you need a p12 key and an account. Have you set that up?

Comment: @MatthewEvans that is only true if you want to access using a service account its not going to help you access a users data.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management)

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources are currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're interested in using these features, request access to the beta.

Google Analytics write opernations are in beta. You say that you have applied and been white-listed.  You must use the Google Developer Project that you applied with to access it.

> Your project does not have access to this feature.

Means that the client id and secrete you are using to authenticate with does not have access to this feature its not part of the project you applied for access with the one that was white listed.

Comment: **Authorization
This request requires authorization with the following scope (read more about authentication and authorization).

Scope
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit
**

This is the scope mentioned at:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/insert

Also , the clientid begins with the project number I requested for whitelisting like
clientid-ftv69u9f7iltciu9bsvi5u66aeium962.apps.googleusercontent.com

So, I'm sure that it is correct.

Is there anything else I might be missing?
@DalmTo

Comment: Contact Google through the Google group you were invited to.  Sounds like there may be some issues with your whitelisted project.    The message says that project isn't white listed  to my knowledge that scope doesn't exist

Comment: Finally it worked, possibly there was an issue with the whitelisting of the project. Thanks for your help @DalmTo  :)

Comment: It can happen they dont give many access to this.   Whitelisting can take a while.   btw i checked with Google https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit is a valid scope.   Remember to accept the anwser if it helped you